# More Efficient Way of Calculating Distances between Numpy Arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

What I have: pre-defined circles at different locations within a 3D box, and particles (with ids and locations in x-y-z coordinate).

What I want to do: find out all the particles within certain radius of each circle, and record their IDs.

What I have been doing: I'm using the distance.cdist() function to compute the euclidean distances between the x-axis positions of all particles and each center of the circles. This is done by looping over all the centers and storing the distances between all particles and each center in different columns.

My code is:

```
p_h_dx = np.empty((len(p),len(dsel))) #I create an empty array
for i in range(len(dsel)): #looping over all centers
    distance = distance.cdist(np.column_stack((p[:,1],p_zeros)),np.column_stack((dsel[:,2][i],0)),'euclidean')
    p_h_dx[:,i] = distance.reshape((len(p),))[:]
```

Then I repeat it for y-axis and z-axis. In the end, I calculate the distances in the following way:

```
###############################################
p_h_dx an array storing the distances between the x-axis positions of all 
particles and centers of the circles;
p_h_dy for y-axis and p_h_dz for z-axis
###############################################
p_h_d = np.sqrt(np.power(p_h_dx,2) + np.power(p_h_dy,2) + np.power(p_h_dz,2))
```

I have more than 100 million particles and ~30 thousand circles, so with my current method, it takes ~1 week to achieve my goal, even with mpi. I'm wondering if there's a way to more efficiently do the job.

Comment: Did you consider using [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)'s?

Comment: probably missing something, any reason why are you splitting distance computation for each coordinate?

Comment: missing something as well, is this 3D distance? A sample would help.